# How to change User representation in Django Admin when used as Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a few models having User as Foreign Key. The User list is displaying the username, but I'd like to customize it. Do I have to extend the User model with a custom model and write my own `__str__` function? Is there an easier way?
I don't think you can use a callable for fieldset, right?

Comment: You can use custom user admin, like @dmitryro. You won't need django-admin-tools to accomplish what you've asked. If you need to show something other than username elsewhere too, I'd recommend using proxy models and overriding __str__ method instead creating custom user model.

Comment: I can create a proxy model for User, but I guess than I must use it as Foreign Key for all models?

Comment: Yes, you will have to.

Comment: I overrode the User __str__ function `User.add_to_class("__str__", get_user_email)` which worked in the admin ListView but not when viewing/adding an individual item.

Comment: Overriding `__unicode__` worked

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think `__unicode__()` method is not the correct, you should use `__str__()` method.

For `Python 2.x`,  `__str__()` method will return str(bytes) and `__unicode__()` method will return unicode (text).

> The print statement and the str built-in call `__str__()` to determine
>   the human-readable representation of an object. The unicode built-in
>   calls  `__unicode__()` if it exists, and otherwise falls back to
>   `__str__()` and decodes the result with the system encoding. Conversely, the Model base class automatically derives `__str__()` from 
>   `__unicode__()` by encoding to UTF-8. 
>   [read here complete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods)

But in `Python 3.x` there is just `__str__()`, no `__unicode__()` method.

> Django provides a simple way to define `__str__()` and  `__unicode__()`
>   methods that work on Python 2 and 3: you must define a `__str__()`
>   method returning text and to apply the [python_2_unicode_compatible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible)()
>   decorator.
>
> On Python 3, the decorator is a no-op. On Python 2, it defines
>   appropriate  `__unicode__()` and `__str__()` methods (replacing the
>   original `__str__()` method in the process).

Here is an example from django docs.

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class MyClass(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Instance of my class"
```

**SOLUTION :** Decorate in the same way, as done above for your Class and
in `models.py`, add a method which will be get added to the User model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def get_name(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

User.add_to_class("__str__", get_name)
```

Comment: The Django base User class has that decorator, so, on load `__unicode__` is set to `__str__'. Therefore, it looks like we would need to override `__unicode__`

Comment: Actually there is no need to override `__unicode__` method, to prevent overriding we are using `add_to_class`

Answer (score 6):

`ForeignKeys` in Django forms are represented by `ModelChoiceFields`.
The `ModelChoiceField` class has a `label_from_instance` method, which decides how to render the choice. So in order to change this representation in the Admin, you need to modify this form field.

Here is a simple example.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        field = super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == "user":
            field.label_from_instance = lambda u: "My Object #%i" % u.id
        return field
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but requires defining a custom admin model for every model.

Comment: good because sometimes you want to change the string representation of a model only in the foreign key dropdowns

Answer (score 3):

You can change the string representation of the Django default User by overriding the User `__unicode__` method. Add the code below somewhere in your app, perhaps in models.py

```
def custom_user_display(self):
    return self.email + ', ' self.first_name # write your representation here

User.add_to_class("__unicode__", custom_user_display) # override the __unicode__ method
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have a model like this

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name='profile')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
```

And you want to show the user's email instead of username or userid in admin page, then you can do something like this

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_user', 'city')

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email
    get_user.short_description = 'User'
    get_user.admin_order_field = 'user__id'
```

Comment: The question is asking about how the User field looks on other objects when User is a foreign key. This will only change the representation on the UserProfile page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had to extend @Todor 's solution for many models and different apps.

In the end, it was better to [override the default AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site) and hook on register to customize the User form fields.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def user_admin_str(instance: get_user_model()) -> str:
    return f"{instance.last_name}-chan"


def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    field = super(ModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
        db_field, request, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(db_field.related_model(), get_user_model()):
        field.label_from_instance = user_admin_str
    return field


def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    field = super(ModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(
        db_field, request, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(db_field.related_model(), get_user_model()):
        field.label_from_instance = user_admin_str
    return field


class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

    def register(self, model_or_iterable, admin_class=None, **options):
        setattr(admin_class, "formfield_for_foreignkey",
                formfield_for_foreignkey)
        setattr(admin_class, "formfield_for_manytomany",
                formfield_for_manytomany)
        super().register(model_or_iterable, admin_class=admin_class, **options)
```

No need to modify every `ModelAdmin` then.